# JavaScript: problem with object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am programming a little timer. The code is as follows:

```
var counter = {
    seconds: 100,
    clock: function () {
        $('input').val(this.seconds);
        this.seconds -= 1;
        setTimeout(this.clock(), 1000);
    }
};

counter.clock();
```

with a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/4ktEG/

Somehow each time I run the code I get a different answer. What is the problem?

Comment: This might give you more of what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/4ktEG/13/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the countdown you're looking for.

```
var counter = {
    seconds: 100,
    clock: function () {
        $('input').val(this.seconds);
        this.seconds -= 1;
        setTimeout(function(){counter.clock()}, 1000);
    }
};

counter.clock();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ktEG/13/

Comment: No problem. I thought initially something else was going on, which was I posted it as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the [`jQuery.proxy()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method  for binding the `this` value.

```
setTimeout($.proxy(counter,'clock'), 1000);
```

The `$.proxy` will return a function that invokes `counter.clock` with `counter` bound as the `this` value.

---

Or you can use it like this to permanently bind `counter` to `counter.clock`:

```
var counter = {
    seconds: 100
};

counter.clock = $.proxy( function () {
    $('input').val(this.seconds);
    this.seconds -= 1;
    setTimeout(this.clock, 1000);
}, counter);

counter.clock();
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bmYAN/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var counter = {
    seconds: 100,
    clock: function () {
        $('input').val(counter.seconds);
        counter.seconds -= 1;
        setTimeout(counter.clock, 1000);
    }
};

counter.clock();
```

You used "this" inside a function, what you want is to refer to the "counter" object.

Comment: I still doesn't do what I want. It shows 100, and then nothing.

Comment: and how is it different? explain please!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the input to show "100", then disappear when the setTimeout is called, then you have to take out the brackets on "this.clock()"

Therefor:

```
var counter = {
seconds: 100,
clock: function () {
    $('input').val(this.seconds);
    this.seconds -= 1;
    setTimeout(this.clock, 1000);
}
};

counter.clock();
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want a **counter** that goes 100, 99, 98, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
setTimeout(this.clock(), 1000); //the clock method will be called right away.
```

Use this instead

```
setTimeout(this.clock, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The timeout will execute in a global context. Hence the 'this' inside the handler will refer to the global context. You have to bind the function to the wanted context to achieve the desired result. Look into `function.call` or `function.apply` which take a context parameter.

```
var counter = {
    seconds: 100,
    clock: function () {
        $('input').val(this.seconds);
        this.seconds -= 1;
        var closure = function() {
            counter.clock.call(counter);
        };

        setTimeout(closure, 1000);
    }
};

counter.clock();
```